# I want all numpy arrays to be forced to be 2 dimensional

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am coming over from Matlab, and while everything was mostly ported over really well (the community has to be thanked for this, a Matlab license costs way over $1000). There is one thing that I cannot for the life of me find out.

In Matlab, all arrays are 2D (until recently, where they gave you other options). Such that, when I define a scalar, array, matrix they are all considered 2D. This is pretty useful when doing matrix multiplication!

In Python, when using numpy. Unfortunately, I find myself having to use the reshape command quite frequently.

**Is there anyway that I can globally set that all array's have 2D dimensions unless stated otherwise?**

Edit:
According to the numpy documentation numpy.matrix may be removed in the coming future. What I want to do in essence is that have all output of any numpy operation have the function **np.atleast_2d** applied to them automatically.

Comment: i cannot understand what you want to do yet. can you explain what you will do with `numpy`?

Comment: Years ago they wrote a `np.matrix` subclass which forces its members to always be 2d.  And its `*` was matrix multiply.  Now most `numpy` developers would like to deprecate it, since it seem to cause more confusion than it helps.  Still some wayward MATLAB coders find it comforting :).  And there is a `scipy` `sparse` matrix module that is 2d.

Comment: Octave is still free :)  and much more like MATLAB.  I'll use that if I'm trying to help with a MATLAB/numpy translation question (or .mat file transfer issue).

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Comment: @Al-BaraaEl-Hag i mean, `list` object in `Python` can be converted into `numpy.ndarray` using like `numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`. So if the input array is 2D matrix, it will converted into 2D `numpy.ndarray`. i think **setting default dimension** is strange.

Comment: This is a really bad idea that would cause all sorts of horrible problems even if you managed to do it. We have enough bugs caused by `numpy.matrix`'s forced-2D behavior without introducing those same bugs throughout the entirety of NumPy and all NumPy-dependent modules you may be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) instead of np.array to define 2D matrices. For example:

```
np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

To convert an array to a matrix use [np.asmatrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.asmatrix.html):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
m = np.asmatrix(a)
```

But as hpaulj mentioned in comments, be aware of:

> It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear
>   algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.

So it's a good idea to get accustomed to using numpy arrays. Have a look at this tutorial
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

To convert scalars or 1D arrays to 2D arrays there is the [np.atleast_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) function

```
np.atleast_2d(3.0)
array([[ 3.]])

np.atleast_2d([1, 2, 3])
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Answer (score 2):

As noted above, the np.matrix class has semantics quite similar to a matlab array.

However, if you goal is to learn numpy as a marketable skill, I would strongly recommend you fully embrace the concept of an ndarray; while there is some historical truth to calling numpy a port of matlab, it is a bit of an insult, as the ndarray is one of the most compelling objective conceptual improvements of numpy over matlab, other than its price.

TLDR; you will have a hard time not getting your application tossed by me if you claim to know numpy, but your code samples smell like ported matlab in any way.

Comment: Avoiding for-loops is indeed even more important than it is in matlab, since matlab for-loops are lightning speed compared to those of python. Generally speaking matlab does not encourage a lot of best-practices in software engineering. Python programmers are very adamant about human-readable variable names, docstrings, intelligent choice of scoping, separation of concerns, a sensible module structure; none of which you will typically find in a ported matlab script.